# How to fix this `FunctionPass` such that it doesn't go into an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

The following code is an attempt to create a `FunctionPass` that iterates over all `BasicBlock`'s, and change `a + b` into `(a xor b) + 2 * (a and b)` for obfuscation.

Now, when I use `ReplaceInstWithValue` the iterator gets invalidated and the program goes into an infinite loop.

I've tried several ways of fixing this, but none has proven useful.

How would I change the program, so that it iterates over ALL instructions in the program without going into an infinite loop on the first `add` instruction?

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/Utils/BasicBlockUtils.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
struct CountOp : public FunctionPass {
    std::map<std::string, int> bbNameToId;

    static char ID;

    CountOp() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {

        for (Function::iterator bs = F.begin(), be = F.end(); bs != be; ++bs) {
            for (BasicBlock::iterator is = bs->begin(), ie = be->end(); is != ie; ++is) {
                Instruction& inst  = *is;
                BinaryOperator* binop = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&inst);

                if (!binop) {
                    continue;
                }

                unsigned opcode = binop->getOpcode();
                errs() << binop->getOpcodeName() << "\n";

                if (opcode != Instruction::Add) {
                    continue;
                }

                IRBuilder<> builder(binop);
                Value* v = builder.CreateAdd(builder.CreateXor(binop->getOperand(0), binop->getOperand(1)), 
                                             builder.CreateMul(ConstantInt::get(binop->getType(), 2), 
                                                               builder.CreateAnd(binop->getOperand(0), binop->getOperand(1))));

                ReplaceInstWithValue(bs->getInstList(), is, v);
            } 
        }   


        return true;
    }
};
}

char CountOp::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<CountOp> X("opChanger", "Change add operations", false, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the problem is in the `for` statement:

`for (BasicBlock::iterator is = bs->begin(), ie = be->end(); is != ie; ++is)`.

`ie` should be initialized to `bs->end()` and not `be->end()`.

Then the example works fine.